# read, update then create another csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

how to update file then create a new csv file with the updated data?

I already read the csv file

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String fileName ="lain.csv";
    File file=new File(fileName);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    
    while(input.hasNext()){
        String data = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

this is the example csv data

> object_name
>
> A.tif
>
> B.tif
>
> C.tif
>
> D.tif

I want to add a comment in each line, with '|' between the data and the comment

for example

> A.tif | this is A

what should I use to make like that?

Comment: why is it `A` not `Copy A` - what would `D.TIF` produce?

Comment: nah thats only an example, i mean i want to add a comment next to the data

Comment: Do you want to create a new file that has all the lines of the source file but additional comments or do you want to add the comments to the original csv file?

Comment: yea, new file with additional comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new file and have the same lines plus comment there, you can do it like this (using `java.nio` for file system access and java 8 iterations):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // the path to your source file as a String
        String fileLocation = "Y:\\our\\path\\to\\lain.csv";
        // the path to your source file as a Path object (java.nio)
        Path filePath = Paths.get(fileLocation);
        // a list of Strings for the new lines, those with a comment separated by |
        List<String> updatedLines = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            // read all the lines of the csv source file into a list
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

            System.out.println("————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————");

            // print each line just to see if everything is properly read (the java 8 way)
            lines.forEach(line -> {
                System.out.println(line);
            });

            System.out.println("————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————");

            // add a comment to each line and store it in the updatedLines 
            lines.forEach(line -> {
                /*
                 * TODO add some line-depending comment creation logic here,
                 * this just adds "a comment" to every line
                 */
                updatedLines.add(line + "|" + "a comment");
            });

            // print the updated lines
            updatedLines.forEach(updatedLine -> {
                System.out.println(updatedLine);
            });

            System.out.println("————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————");

            // create a new file
            String updatedFileLocation = "Y:\\our\\path\\to\\lain_updated.csv";
            Path updatedFilePath = Paths.get(updatedFileLocation);
            Files.createFile(updatedFilePath);

            // write the updated lines to a new csv file
            Files.write(updatedFilePath, updatedLines,
                    StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);

            // final check: read the new file and print its content:
            Files.readAllLines(updatedFilePath).forEach(writtenUpdatedLine -> {
                System.out.println(writtenUpdatedLine);
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can u explain why we should use ArrayList for this? and what is  'StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1' ?

Comment: I just took the `ArrayList`, you can take everything that implements the `List` interface. The `StandardCharsets` provide options for different file encodings while reading the file content. If your lain.csv is encoded in UTF-8, you can choose that charset. Have you tried it? Does the code work in your environment?

Comment: @CalvinAdiwinata sure, I cannot know your paths... Do you mind accepting my answer if it was what you were asking for?